# Connecting to Google Drive using Python(PyDrive)

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api, pydrive

I have this code:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import time
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Auto-iterate through all files that matches this query
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
print 'title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id'])
time.sleep(1)
```

However, each time I want to run it, it opens my browser and asks for permission to access google drive. How to bypass it? I mean at least ask once, then save the "permission" and don't ask again or (which would be best) silently accept the permission in the background without my decision. I have downloaded client_secrets.json which is used for passing the authorization details.

What if I wanted to release my application? I mean I had to generate + download the client_secrets.json in order to make it work. I guess my users wouldn't wanto to do so. Is there any better, more convenient way?

I would also appreciate a tutorial-for-dummies about using Google Drive API because it's hard for me to understand it reading the documentation alone.

Comment: If you want to access users data without any manual authorization from them, use service account. Here is the link for the detail description https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation.You can check the code sample in the link.

Comment: I think the service account is seperate from MyDrive and cannot be accessed via the web interface if this is important.

Comment: So what is the best way to access Google Drive in the fastest way and least work-demanding from user?

Answer (score 0):

pydrive2 has done a fabulous job of automating the authentication file via settings.yaml file. Use the below package if you are experiencing the above problem

https://docs.iterative.ai/PyDrive2/